# Using enums for type checking -- how to scope properly

Tags: c++, enums, scope, type-safety

I have a mixture of C++ classes, some of which store a state variable 0..9 as integer, others use '0' ... '9'.  Currently I do:

```
enum { kOne = '1' };
class StoresValueAsInt {
    static int value;  // contains 0 ... 9
};
class StoresValueAsChar {
    static char value; // contains '0' ... '9'
};
class StoresValueAsChar {
    static char value;
};

template <typename X>
isOne() { return X::value == kOne; }
```

This allows me to write the buggy code `isOne<StoresValueAsInt::value>()`.  Instead, I would like to have the compiler complain about this incorrect usage.  I tried the following:

```
enum ValueInt {
    kOne = 1
};
enum ValueChar {
    kOne = '1'
};

class StoresValueAsInt {
    static ValueInt value;
};
class StoresValueAsChar {
    static ValueChar value;
};
class StoresValueAsChar2 {
    static ValueChar value;
};
```

However, this does not work, because kOne is visible at the namespace level, and thus it has conflicting declarations of kOne.

Is there a way to not have the enums declared in the namespace?  Or a better approach here?

*updated:*  Added what I currently do; hoping to clarify my use case.

Comment: The compiler is not going to complain about a comparison between a `char` and an `int` because a `char` is an `unsigned int` (or `unsigned short` on some systems)

Comment: Yes, then compiler does not complain about the error in the first version.  This is why I wanted to define enums to have a type check; and the compiler would consider ValueInt and ValueChar as being different...

Comment: Yes, I am using your solution -- as you have stated "this is ugly," so my initial hope was that there is a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as best practice, I'm really not sure what you are trying to accomplish here so I can't point you in the right direction.

However, to answer your question directly: Placing the enums in seperate namespaces would solve your issue:

```
namespace IntVals {
   enum ValueInt {
      kOne = 1
   };
}
namespace CharVals {
   enum ValueChar {
      kOne = '1'
   };
}

class StoresValueAsInt {
   static ValueInt value;
};
class StoresValueAsChar {
   static ValueChar value;
};
```

Then you should be able to use the following:

```
StoresValueAsInt::value == CharVals::kOne
```

Though this is ugly, and I wish I understood better what you were going for to offer a more elegant solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to not have the enums declared in the namespace? Or a better approach here?

Yes, you can differentiate your enums as below:

```
struct ValueInt {
  enum {  // no need to have enum Name
    kOne = 1
  };
};
struct ValueChar {
  enum {  // no need to have enum Name
    kOne = '1'
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
ValueInt::kOne;
ValueChar::kOne;
```